# convert database object to string in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    security_question = models.CharField('Question', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    security_answer = models.CharField('Answer', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_daytime = models.CharField('Phone daytime', max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_mobile = models.CharField('Phone mobile', max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    work_street = models.CharField('Street', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    work_suburb = models.CharField('Suburb', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    work_state = models.CharField('State', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    work_postcode = models.CharField('Postcode', max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    work_country = models.CharField('Country', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def method(request):
    ''''
    profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
    '''''
    return render(request,'index.html',{'profile':profile})
```

How to convert the database field's work_street,work_suburb,work_state,work_postcode, work_country into string and render it in template.

Comment: You don't have to. `{{ profile.work_street }}` will render it perfectly fine in your template.

Comment: @limelights The 4 field what i mentioned is the address of the work place,i want to pass that as string in javascript for fixing marker in position so i can do like this for mentioning address var address = "{{ profile.work_street }}{{profile.work_suburb}}{{profile.work_postcode}}"; is it right way if not please correct me how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create index.html like this to render it as html

#### index.html

```
<body>
<p>{{ profile.user.username }}</p>
<p>{{ profile.security_question }}</p>
<p>{{ profile.work_street}}</p>
<p>{{ profile.work_suburb}}</p>
<p>{{ profile.work_state}}</p>
<p>{{ profile.work_postcode}}</p>
<p>{{ profile.work_country }}</p>
..... etc

<script>
 var address = "{{ profile.work_street }}{{profile.work_suburb}}{{profile.work_postcode}}";
 alert(address);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: want to pass that as string in javascript for fixing marker in position so i can do like this for mentioning address var address = "{{ profile.work_street }}{{profile.work_suburb}}{{profile.work_postcode}}"; is it right way if not please correct me.

Comment: @Royal yes you can defenitily do that. that is the correct way. when page loads the string will store in `address`